# Quelles seraient des variantes possibles de « Je tiens en mépris ceux qui confondent éducation avec intelligence » ?

Tags: formulation, synonymes, reformulation

> Je tiens en mépris ceux qui confondent éducation avec intelligence.

> Je tiens en mépris ceux qui confondent éducation et intelligence.

> Je tiens en mépris ceux qui confondent le niveau d’étude avec/et l’intelligence.

Pour être plus précis, je cherche par dessus-tout des variantes de « confondre éducation et/avec intelligence.

Comment: Dans le TLFi, regarde ce qui est en vert pour des syntagmes (ou formules/tournures typiques).

Comment: « Confondre » serait à prendre dans le sens de considérer comme valides sans les tester les raisonnements dont les sources sont des diplômés tout en rejetant sans les examiner ceux dont les sources ne sont pas légitimées par des diplômes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avec le verbe *confondre*, on peut employer autant *avec* que *et* ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/confondre), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/confondre/18132)). Voir par exemple pour des synonymes : [*confondre*](https://www.synonymes.com/synonyme.php?mot=confondre), [*éducation*](https://www.synonymes.com/synonyme.php?mot=%E9ducation), [*intelligence*](https://www.synonymes.com/synonyme.php?mot=intelligence).

> ...ceux qui confondent/mélangent succès académique et facultés
> intellectuelles.
>  ...ceux qui assimilent le niveau d'étude [à](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/rdp-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=assimiler&i=1&cur=1&nmbr=1&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0)
> l'intelligence. [je trouve moins usuel]
>  ...ceux qui
> voient/établissent un lien direct entre le niveau d'étude et la
> matière grise.
>  ...ceux qui ne peuvent faire la différence entre le
> nombre de diplômes et la capacité à raisonner.